# why is log4net appearing in console and not text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, console, log4net

Trying to use log4net in a console application. I have followed [this tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/MarkPearl/archive/2012/01/30/log4net-basics-with-a-console-application-c.aspx) and everything works fine up until part 4: the log file is not created, **instead** the logs are outputted on the command prompt.

Tired manually creating the file but no joy

Anyone know why?
seems in the reviews at the bottom people have had the same problem but no resolve?

**UPDATE**
forgot to mention i changed the file location to

```
<file value="C:\Users\John\Desktop\log4net.txt" />
```

but I have no problems with permissions so shouldnt matter

Answer (score 0):

So from the link the config file looks like:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
  <file value="c:\\mylogfile.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</root>
```

Is it possible you do not have rights to the "C:\" on your machine?   Try dropping the path - by default it will write to the root of your console project file folder.  If it works must have something to do with file permissions.

**Actually I missed this:**  type="xxx.FileAppender , log4net"    Drop the ",log4net" portion and it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention I changed the path to <file value="C:\Users\John\Desktop\log4net.txt" />    I will try your suggestion though

Comment: sorry no joy...with either suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties of log4net.config file and set the property "Copy To Output Directory" to "Copy always".